# apply same options to multiple routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

Let say I have following conditions to apply on a bunch of resources:

```
:only => [:create, :destroy], :defaults => {:format => :json}, :constraints => {:format => :json}
```

My question is how can I apply these conditions to multiple routes at once, e.g:

```
group resources [:resource1, :resource2] do
    :only => [:create, :destroy], :defaults => {:format => :json}, :constraints => {:format => :json}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`routes.rb` is just ruby, so you can place ruby code on top like this

```
my_defaults = { 
  only:        [:create, :destroy], 
  defaults:    { format: :json }, 
  constraints: { format: :json }
}

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # ...
  resources :users, my_defaults
  # ...
end
```